# Detecting changes on Angular bound observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

This is a retry of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50510831/how-to-synchronize-changes-with-server-in-angular-6) which I suppose I asked incorrectly

I am trying to detect changes made by a component subscribed to a service. The component file is:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import {Item} from './app.module';
import { DataService } from './data.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  items: Item[];

  constructor(
    public dataService: DataService
  ){

  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.dataService.getItems().subscribe(items=>{
      this.items = items;
    });
  }
}
```

while the service.ts is:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject , Observable, of, throwError } from 'rxjs'

import { Item } from './app.module';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  private _items: BehaviorSubject<Item[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
  public readonly items$: Observable<Item[]> = this._items.asObservable();

  private first:boolean = true;

  constructor() {
    this._items.next([{name:'first',id:1},{name:'second',id:2}] as Item[]);
    this.monitorChanges();
  }

  getItems(): Observable <Item[]>{
    return this.items$;
  }

  monitorChanges(){
    this._items.subscribe(items => {
      console.log("_items updated");
    });
  }
}
```

How can I implement `monitorChanges()` so that it will fire whenever the component makes changes to its local this.items? I am planning on using the component to edit the items and then have the service sync changes with a server. Thank you!

A live example is on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-asuepv)

Running:
Angular CLI: 6.0.3
Angular: 6.0.1
rxjs: 6.1.0

~~~~~~~

**I discovered my ignorance** - I was operating on the assumption that .subscribe(x=> this.x=x) created a new copy of x that Angular magically tracked. I was hoping that there was some way to tap into that to detect changes. This is incorrect. All of my components are manipulating the same object, the observable just passes references. This is even the case for .pipe(map(...)).

Comment: onItemChanges(){
    return this._items
  }

Comment: I don't believe I understand. I am trying to run code whenever a change happens, not return something. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Your this._items is a behaviorsubject, and you use _items.next to update the items saved by this subject. so you can just return this subject and let other component subscribe ,

Comment: @BobtheMagicMoose so what you want is that you have two different components that can update the `items`, and you want a "centralized" place to monitor if those items has changed?

Comment: @CozyAzure Exactly, I want a centralized location for data management (as I believe that is how Angular is designed?). I am a little confused as to how `ngOnInit(){
    this.dataService.getItems().subscribe(items=>{
      this.items = items;
    });
  }` results in a synchronized copy of the items. This might be the root of my confusion.

Comment: Your component should call service methods when it needs to update the items. If that service exposes a BehaviorSubject that should fire whenever the items change, then the service should call this._items.next() whenever changes are done.

Comment: @Davy, I understand the reasoning behind creating an interface between the service and the components and requiring the component to call service methods to make changes --- however, most of the examples I see on the internet have them sharing data objects (usually through observables) which would imply direct access to the data item. Wouldn't using service methods go against the paradigm of sharing data between components?